# Push-Notification in react-native

Tags: react-native, react-native-push-notification

Is it necessary to do manual installation for react-native-push-notification as mentioned in library npm page. I did it but  its not working. Can some share the latest example for the same.

Is there any alternative to react-native-push-notification.

Comment: which version of RN are you using?

Comment: react-native version-0.60.5

Comment: yes, even with auto linking some manual installation is required

Comment: @GauravRoy how to find googlePlayServiceVersion as it mentioned that googlePlayServiceVersion and firebase-messaging should have same version number

Answer (score 0):

You can user  react-native-firebase npm package, it is a well documented library for push notifications and cloud messaging.